# PHP Replace every non-alphanumeric character with a space

Tags: php, preg-replace

I've searched and searched. I can't find the solution. I have a string that goes a little something like this: ABC_test 001-2.jpg

I also have this bit of code:

```
$makeSpace = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", "&nbsp;", $replaceUnder);
```

However, this bit of code will not replace the underscore (_). In fact, the output of this variable is: ABC

So it stops once it hits the underscore. I need to replace EVERY possible non-alphanumeric character, including the underscore, asterisks, question marks, whatever. What am I missing?

Thanks for the help.

EDIT:

```
<?php
       //set images directory
        $directory = 'ui/images/customFabrication/';
        try {
            // create slideshow div to be manipulated by the above jquery function
            echo "<div class=\"slideLeft\"></div>";
                echo "<div class=\"sliderWindow\">";
                    echo "<ul id=\"slider\">";
            //iterate through the directory, get images, set the path and echo them in img tags.
            foreach ( new DirectoryIterator($directory) as $item ) {
                if ($item->isFile()) {
                    $path = $directory . "" . $item;
                    $class = substr($item, 0,-4); //removes file type from file name
                    //$replaceUnder = str_replace("_", "-", $class);
                    $makeDash = str_replace(" ", "-", $replaceUnder);

                    $replaceUnder = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", " ", $class);

                    //$makeSpace = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", "&nbsp;", $replaceUnder);
                    echo "<li><img rel=" . $replaceUnder . " class=" . $class . " src=\"/ui/js/timthumb.php?src=/" . $path . "&h=180&w=230&zc=1\" /></li>";
                }
            }
                    echo "</ul>";
                echo "</div>";
            echo "<div class=\"slideRight\"></div>";
        }
       //if directory is empty throw an exception.
        catch(Exception $exc) {
            echo 'the directory you chose seems to be empty';
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: This code looks fine to me. Are you sure `$replaceUnder` contains what you think it does (and that you really are viewing what `$makeSpace` contains)?

Comment: crap, why there isn't a rule obliging OPs **to post reproduceable code?** Why should I write it myself?

Comment: dude. don't post your code. **You have to try arnorhs' code instead**. And tell us result

Comment: I tried it, but ended up with the same results. My code is a little different than the original code I posted, so I wanted to post it all just in case...

Answer (score 4):

I can't reproduce your problem, for me the string that gets outputted is:

```
$replaceUnder = 'ABC_test 001-2.jpg';
$makeSpace = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", "&nbsp;", $replaceUnder);
print_r($makeSpace);

# output:
# ABC test 001 2 jpg
```

.

## dubugging your code

I went through the code you pasted in and found a few errors, which are maybe related, maybe not:

I get an error on this line, because replaceUnder is not defined:

```
$makeDash = str_replace(" ", "-", $replaceUnder);
```

since you commented this line out:

```
//$replaceUnder = str_replace("_", "-", $class);
```

I guess you meant to comment it out as well. It's not clear at all what you're trying to do and why you have all those replace statements. If you're just trying to echo out the file names with all the symbols replaced, this is how I did it and the letters all got replaced with spaces:

```
<?php
//set images directory
$directory = './';
try {
    foreach ( new DirectoryIterator($directory) as $item ) {
        if ($item->isFile()) {
            $path = $directory . "" . $item;
            // remove ending/filetype - the other method doesn't support 4 letter file endings
            $name = basename($item);
            $fixedName = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", " ", $name);
            echo "Name: $fixedName\n";
        }
    }
            
}
//if directory is empty throw an exception.
catch(Exception $exc) {
    echo 'the directory you chose seems to be empty';
}
?>
```

I think your whole problems stem from the naming of variables. Consider turning on notice errors - they will let you know if you're referencing variables that aren't defined.

Comment: Ok, this is what I'm trying to do. I'm successfully pulling all file names from a directory, and then with those file names applying classes and rels. This is my full code. Here is my code

Comment: `$directory = 'ui/images/customFabrication/';
         try {
             // create slideshow div to be manipulated by the above jquery function
             echo "<div class=\"slideLeft\"></div>";
              echo "<div class=\"sliderWindow\">";
               echo "<ul id=\"slider\">";
             //iterate through the directory, get images, set the path and echo them in img tags.
             foreach ( new DirectoryIterator($directory) as $item ) {`

Comment: `if ($item->isFile()) {
                     $path = $directory . "" . $item;
      $class = substr($item, 0,-4); //removes file type from file name
                     //$replaceUnder = str_replace("_", "-", $class);
                     $makeDash = str_replace(" ", "-", $replaceUnder);`

Comment: `$replaceUnder = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", " ", $class);
 
                     //$makeSpace = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", "&nbsp;", $replaceUnder);
                     echo "<li><img rel=" . $replaceUnder . " class=" . $class . " src=\"/ui/js/timthumb.php?src=/" . $path . "&h=180&w=230&zc=1\" /></li>";
                 }`

Comment: wow. sorry for the insane comments. I'll edit my original post.